# Flutter "Unable to Find Target Name"

Tags: flutter, dart, cocoapods, macbookpro

I've seen several threads that start to address this issue but none have solved mine. Having an error trying to compile on my 2023 M2 MacBook Pro.

Error: [!] Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`.

Here is some the error and the Flutter Doctor.
Installed through HomeBrew

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.1, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta), locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.13.1 on channel stable at /Users/brennanaltringer/Documents/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision e1e47221e8 (4 days ago), 2023-08-22 21:43:18 -0700
    • Engine revision b20183e040
    • Dart version 3.1.0
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/brennanaltringer/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
    • VS Code at /Users/brennanaltringer/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.70.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone arm64 (mobile)  • emulator-5554                        • android-arm64 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile) • 38B5F0BC-D398-4800-900F-624FE2D8974D • ios           • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-arm64  • macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta)

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Error on compile:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             384ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    [!] Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`.

    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:108:in `compute_targets'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:40:in `compute_results'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1197:in `block (3 levels) in
    inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1195:in `each'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1195:in `block (2 levels) in
    inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `each'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1188:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:107:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

I am also getting an error in my Runner in Xcode complaining about "Module 'assets_audio_player' not found"

I've tried ever version online for reinstalling pod with gem and brew, paths are updated and pointing in the right direction. Flutter clean and all those easy stuff didn't work either. I believe Ruby is up to date. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns our deleting the iOS folder and using 'flutter create .' did the trick.